# Using C compiled code from python GUI

Tags: c++, python, c, wxpython

I am writing an application where I am coding all of my front-end and GUI with python library (wxpython specifically). For this application, I would like to write the model class with C and use python to use the compiled C code? How can this be implemented in python?

I know this is little vague question but I am struggling with the starting point.

Comment: [Cython](http://cython.org/) might be an option for you.

Comment: Are you looking for *ctypes*? http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CPython (the most popular version of Python), you'll need to learn the [CPython C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/). Other python implementations may or may not support C calls. You can also use the [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) library which is easier to learn, but also more rigid and may not support everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Cython](http://cython.org/), which is basically Python with embedded support for C types and  calls (it goes through the CPython API).

Answer (score 1):

You could strictly seperate design(python part) and code(c++ part) like this:

Write a complete c++ programm that works in the terminal/console and then make the python-application call these c++-terminal programm via os.Popen.

So if your programm is a calculator it does this:

(python gui) 5 + 5 -> my_c_programm.exe "5 + 5" -> (returns) 10 -> (python gui) display

that way you can use your programm with and without gui.

Its easier and faster than embedding Python in your c++ programm or extending Python with C++.

I basically do the same thing on my current project, but like this:

php: my webinterface
python: for structure and logic and easy operation
c++: for heavy calculations and where I need speed

so php -> python -> c++

and it works very well for me :)